# data fetched from api is not passed as props to nested component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react app I have a main App component where I fetched data from api in componentDidMount method and saved it in its state. Then I passed that state to another component in App. However, when I consume that data from prop it is showing undefined.
Another strange this I didn't is when I console.log state in App components render method them first I get an empty array then after a second another array with the data in it. Please help me here
The code goes like this-

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
    }

    fetchData() {
        fetch(
            `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=${
                process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
            }&language=en-US&page=1`
        )
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ data });
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.data);
        return (
            <div>
                <Movie title="Popular" results={this.state.data} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

this.state.data is undefined in Movie component which is like this

```
function Movie(props) {
  return (
    <p>{props.data.results[0].title}</p>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `results` and `title` as the `props` to the `<Movie>` component yet trying to fetch `data` prop.

**component:**

```
<Movie title="Popular" results={this.state.data} />
```

So you need to fetch the `results` prop, not the data one.

**fixed:**

```
function Movie(props) {
  return (
    <p>{props.results[0].title}</p>
  )
}
```

---

**additionaly:**

If you're already passing the title prop, why not just use that prop for the title?

```
function Movie(props) {
  return (
    <p>{props.title}</p>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your prop is `results` so you need to reference that in your component:

```
function Movie(props) {
  return (
    <p>{props.results[0].title}</p>
  )
}
```

In your App component you might also want to add a check in `render` to show a loading message or spinner if the data load hasn't been resolved when the component initially renders:

```
if (!this.state.data.length) return <Spinner />;
```